# Replace everything in string except letters and spaces

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace everything in a string except letters AND spaces. How would I do that?

```
$str = "one two three !@#$%^&*()_+|";
$str = preg_replace('/\PL/u', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

**Result:**

```
onetwothree
```

**Want Result:**

```
one two three
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^\p{L} ]+/u', '', $str);
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/jI1mX3/1)

The idea is to replace multiples (`+`) of non (`^`) letters (`\p{L}`) or spaces.

Comment: `preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\s]/u', '', $str);`